# read a text file from S3 into a Spark df : UsupportedOperationException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read a text file from on-prem s3 compatible object storage using Spark and I am getting an error stating: UsupportedOperationException. I am unsure what this is pointing to and have tried to adjust code thinking maybe it was the spark.read command.  I have tried read.text and read.csv both of which should work, but result in the same error. Full stack trace is below along with code:

Code being used:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("s3reader") \
            .getOrCreate()\

sc = spark.sparkContext

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key","xxxxxxxxxxxx")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")

df = spark.read.text("https://s3a.us-east-1.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/bronze/xxxxxxx/test.txt")

print(df)
```

Stack trace:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloud/sparks3test.py", line 19, in <module>
    df = spark.read.text("https://s3a.us-east-1.tpavcps3ednrg1.vici.verizon.com/bronze/CoreMetrics/test.txt")
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 516, in text
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/local/bin/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.text.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.AbstractHttpFileSystem.listStatus(AbstractHttpFileSystem.java:91)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.http.HttpsFileSystem.listStatus(HttpsFileSystem.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.listLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.$anonfun$parallelListLeafFilesInternal$1(HadoopFSUtils.scala:95)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFilesInternal(HadoopFSUtils.scala:85)
        at org.apache.spark.util.HadoopFSUtils$.parallelListLeafFiles(HadoopFSUtils.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex$.bulkListLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.listLeafFiles(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.refresh0(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InMemoryFileIndex.<init>(InMemoryFileIndex.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createInMemoryFileIndex(DataSource.scala:581)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:417)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.text(DataFrameReader.scala:944)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try reading file from S3 like below.

```
s3a://bucket/bronze/xxxxxxx/test.txt
```